# Obtain z test statistic for testing Spearman rho with z-score formula

Tags: statistical-significance, spearman-rho

I know the approach using student t-test to derive p-value from spearman rho coefficient. I also saw [permutation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests) for this operation, but I am somehow confused and prefer to stick to the z-score formula $\frac{x-\mu}\sigma$.

In other words, how can I convert Spearman rho coefficient to the normal approximation z statistic with formula z-score formula $\frac{x-\mu}\sigma$?

Link to related unanswered question: [Spearman rho statistical significance value (z)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217422/spearman-rho-statistical-significance-value-z)

Comment: Please let me know in comment if I am missing something.

Comment: Link to related unanswered question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217422/spearman-rho-statistical-significance-value-z

Comment: I don't think you can use $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ to convert Spearman's $\rho$ to z-score here. You need Fisher transformation as the linked wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance) on the question in your comment shows. Check this question and Nick Cox's answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59714/testing-spearmans-rho-between-groups . I don't think it is hard to use Fisher transformation to obtain z-score.

Comment: The problem is I get different p-value using fisher transformation and t-distribution. For example in the [wikipedia xample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance), rho=-0.1757 and p-value=0.62. Using Fisher transformation. I get F(r)=Arctan(-0.1757)=-0.1775 and z-score=SQRT((10-3)/1.06)*-0.1775=-0.456. Using normal distribution table, pvalue==2*(1-NORMSDIST(ABS(-0.456)))=0.648 which is different from wikipedia example

Comment: Also in the [page you sent](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261457/obtain-z-score-from-spearman-r-with-z-score-formula), I used Glen_b formula for variance: (n1+n2−6/1.06), so variance=(10+10-6)/1.06=13.20. zscore=-0.1757/sqrt(13.20)=0.96 which is wrong

Comment: You obtain different p-values because you use different distributions: t distribution and normal distribution. Calculate t on that wiki page and compare results. I don't get why you divide $\rho$ with the $\sqrt{13.20}$

Comment: because I tried to use $\frac{x-\mu}\sigma$ formula

Comment: I see and I am sorry if I misled you, but don't get confused with Glen_b's answer. That question is about comparing two separate correlations ("running separate Spearman's analyses for each group"). I sent it to show that using Fisher transformation for Spearman's $\rho$ is admissible.

Comment: I edited the title and partly the body of your question. You are asking about z test statistic. It is a value, z-score  in standard normal distribution. However, the notion "z-score" is wider than only that in the normal distribution. Therefore we should not equate concepts "z-score" and "normal test statistic z".

Answer (score 4):

Let $R^x_1, R^x_2,\ldots, R^x_{n_x}$ be the ranks of $x$ and $R^y_1, R^y_2,\ldots,R^y_{n_y}$ be the ranks of $y$.  Spearman correlation is determined as
\begin{equation}
r_s = 1 - \frac{6D}{n^3-n}
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
D = \sum_{i=1}^n  d_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (R^x_{(i)}-R^y_{(i)})^2
\end{equation}

Significance testing of $r_s$ is based on the standard normal distribution.  Using the expected value of $D$ as 
\begin{equation}
E(D)  = \frac{n^3-n}{6} = \frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{6}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V(D)  = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)}{36}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Z  = \frac{D - E(D)}{\sqrt{V(D)}} \Longrightarrow \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}
\end{equation}

Comment: you're welcome. It is the closed form approximation that works, so testing is not really needed, unless you mean "debug your code."