# can you transform spearmans r into pearsons r for meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, pearson-r, spearman-rho, z-score

my meta analysis involves the calculation of overall effect size based on pearsons r correlations within studies. I am already converting the pearsons r to fishers z scores for analysis but I have a study that reports spearmans r. I am wondering if I would be able to convert the spearmans r into fishers z in the same way please?

Thanks

Comment: if you have $n$ you should be able to use this answer I think ... ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261457/obtain-z-test-statistic-for-testing-spearman-rho-with-z-score-formula

Comment: Thanks Ben , is there a calculator for this that anyone knows of please?

Comment: I started to do the algebra but ran out of steam.  Maybe you could do the algebra ...?

Comment: Of course you can apply the same formula--but since the two versions of $r$ do not reflect the same property of the data, it would make little sense to compare them or to compare any transformed versions of them.

Comment: whuber does that mean a spearmans rank r should be excluded if I am interested in correlations of pearsons r?

Comment: Ben , I can`t get very far with the algebra myself either. I have access to an r to z calculator but I am unsure if it is acceptable to use this for a spearmans r

Comment: It really depends on how much of a stickler you want to be. If all you have is the Spearman r and the sample size, then there is no way to recover the Pearson's r, and a Fisher's z is still not a Fisher's z of a Pearson's r. However, you have the problem of either leaving this study out, which is not ideal, or using Spearman's r as an estimate of Pearson's r, which is also not ideal. My preference is the treat it as an imperfect estimate of Pearson's r and proceed as normal. Then do a sensitivity analysis that excludes this study. Meta-analysts often use approximations to desired effect sizes.